# Applying Groupby function to multiple column in python and calculation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use `groupby` in python to divide the `INPUT_DF` based on two columns `ID` and `DATE(MM/DD/YY)` and then perform mathematical operation  on the grouped rows.

The Math function for the grouped Rows is: `EXPOSURE * VALUE`. For the grouped `ID` and `DATE` there might be multiple exposures in that case it should be `SUM(EXPOSURE * VALUE)`

INPUT_DF:

```
ID  PRODUCT EXPOSURE    DATE(MM/DD/YY)  VALUE
STA A   0.5 1/31/03 3
STA A   0.5 8/29/03 4
MP  B   0.6 8/29/03 5
MP  B   0.5 5/31/05 6
ZT  B   0.3 5/31/05 7
ZT  B   0.5 5/31/05 8
STA A   0.6 1/31/03 1
STA A   0.7 8/29/03 2
MP  B   0.8 8/29/03 3
MP  B   0.2 5/31/05 4
ZT  B   0.5 5/31/05 5
ZT  B   0.2 6/31/05 6
```

OUTPUT_DF:

```
ID  DATE    FINAL_VALUE
STA 1/31/03 2.1
STA 8/29/03 3.4
MP  8/29/03 5.4
MP  5/31/05 3.8
ZT  5/31/05 8.6
ZT  6/31/05 1.2
```

CODE:

I did try to do the following

```
OUTPUT_DF  = INPUT_DF[['ID','DATE(MM/DD/YY)']].groupby('ID', 'DATE(MM/DD/YY)')['EXPOSURE']*['VALUE'].sum()
```

But it is giving me an error. Can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: Can you post what the exact error you're getting is?

Comment: For starters, you need to pass columns as a list. `.groupby('ID', 'DATE(MM/DD/YY)')` should be `.groupby(['ID', 'DATE(MM/DD/YY)'])`

Comment: `df.groupby(["ID", "DATE"]).apply(lambda x: sum(x["VALUE"]*x["EXPOSURE"]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
OUTPUT_DF = (INPUT_DF.groupby(['ID', 'DATE(MM/DD/YY)'])
             .apply(lambda x: sum(x.EXPOSURE * x.VALUE)))


ID   DATE(MM/DD/YY)
MP   5/31/05           3.8
     8/29/03           5.4
STA  1/31/03           2.1
     8/29/03           3.4
ZT   5/31/05           8.6
     6/31/05           1.2
```

To get it as a dataframe in the format you have posted, just add `to_frame` and `reset_index`:

```
OUTPUT_DF = (INPUT_DF.groupby(['ID', 'DATE(MM/DD/YY)'])
             .apply(lambda x: sum(x.EXPOSURE * x.VALUE))
             .to_frame('FINAL_VALUE')
             .reset_index())

>>> OUTPUT_DF
    ID DATE(MM/DD/YY)  FINAL_VALUE
0   MP        5/31/05          3.8
1   MP        8/29/03          5.4
2  STA        1/31/03          2.1
3  STA        8/29/03          3.4
4   ZT        5/31/05          8.6
5   ZT        6/31/05          1.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I get the ID for all the missing date. I am interested in `output` as shown in the question.

Comment: You're welcome! See my edit, I think that takes care of it

Comment: you should be careful with using `.apply` as it can run quite slowly on larger datasets.

Comment: @asongtoruin, that's absolutely true.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate your sumproduct column before you apply your `groupby`, and then simply `sum`:

```
input_df['FINAL_VALUE'] = input_df['VALUE'] * input_df['EXPOSURE']

output_df = input_df.groupby(['ID', 'DATE(MM/DD/YY)'])['FINAL_VALUE'].sum()

print(output_df)
```

This prints:

```
ID   DATE(MM/DD/YY)
MP   5/31/05           3.8
     8/29/03           5.4
STA  1/31/03           2.1
     8/29/03           3.4
ZT   5/31/05           8.6
     6/31/05           1.2
```